# C - What should scripts do in programs

Tags: c, scripting, lua, language-agnostic, scripting-language

If I want to create a game in C with SDL for example, is there a reason of why I should use a scripting language like Lua with it (since alot of commercial games uses a scripting language)? I have heard that scripting languages often are faster to write and easier to read, but what should they do? (graphics? ai? input? etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should interact with the various "programming primitives" that the native code implements. That is, the native code should only do enough to allow the scripts to function within the game (although "function" can sometimes mean speed-wise).

If that sounds cyclical... it is. There's no complete way to define at the beginning of development what responsibilities the native code will have as the project progresses.